# Creating a loop in python

Tags: python, loops

I have two seperate dataframes that share the same columns, one of which is Product_Id

I am trying to create a loop at will go through one dataframe's Product_Id and if the Ids are the same in the other dataframe to update an existing column with is the market, below is the code that i have written but i am unable to get the needed result :

```
for i in dfproductoligo['Product_Id']:
if dfproductoligo['Product_Id'].isin(dfproductcpal['Product_Id']):
    dfproductoligo['Marché'] = "CPAL + Oligo"
else: dfproductoligo['Marché'] ="Oligo"
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to get the needed result"? Is your code failing with a SyntaxError? Is it running but not giving you the expected output? I highly recommend looking at this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can define the cpal products you want to compare your oligo list to. Then you use a function to loop over your oligo products and check the match.

```py
def check_same_market(row, cpal_products):
    market = ""
    if row['Product_Id'] in cpal_products:
        market = "CPAL + Oligo"
    return market

cpal_products = list(dfproductcpal['Product_Id'].unique())

dfproductoligo['Marché'] = dfproductoligo.apply(check_same_market, args=(cpal_products,), axis=1)
```

Hope that makes sense